# JSON data is returned as undefined after rendered using ajax JQuery in ASP.NET Core MVC app

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

[Please click here to see the debugged result and rendered data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vv4eJ.png)

I'm developing a function in an ASP.NET Core MVC app that for each time I click on the dropdown list item, it will render a respective data based on the item's id.

This is my actions in the controller

```
// this function get list of course and render a dropdown list of courses.
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    List<SelectListItem> listItem = new List<SelectListItem>();
    var courses = await _context.Course.ToListAsync();

    foreach (var course in courses)
    {
        listItem.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = course.CourseName, Value = course.CourseId.ToString() });
    }

    ViewBag.CourseList = listItem;
    return View();
}
```

This is a function that returns a partial view as JSON data that depending on the course's id.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetNoteById(int id)
{
    var noteModel = await _context.Course
                                  .Include(n => n.Notices)
                                  .AsNoTracking()
                                  .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.CourseId == id);

    if (noteModel == null)
        return Json(new { data = NotFound(), message = "Error while retrieving data." });

    return Json(noteModel);
}
```

And this is my `.cshtml` file

```
// some code ....

<div class="col-sm-4 offset-4 form-inline">
    <label class="">Courses </label>
    <select id="courses_dropdown_list" class="custom-select ml-2"
            asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.CourseList, "Value","Text") )">
    </select>
</div>

// some code ...

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>File Type</th>
                <th>File</th>
                <th>Created On</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="note_table">

          // partial view will be loaded in here 
        </tbody>
</table>
```

And finally, this is my ajax script that helps render JSON data.

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#courses_dropdown_list").change(function () {
        var id = $("#courses_dropdown_list").val();
        var noteTable = $("#note_table");
        var result = "";
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "GET",
            url: "@Url.Action("GetNoteById", "Note")",
            datatype: "json",
            data: { "id": id },
            success: function (data) {
                noteTable.html("");
                $.each(data, function (id, note) {
                    /* this is what I tried to debug 
                    there is no problem with the data 
                    but when it is renderd, it returned undefined */

                    console.log(id);
                    console.log(note);

                    result += `
                        <tr>
                            <td>${note.Id}</td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="/note/NoteDetail/${note.Id}" class="nav-link mt-0">${note.Name}</a>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="/note/DowloadNoteFromDB/${note.Id}" class="nav-link mt-0">###</a>
                            </td>
                            <td>{note.FileType}</td>
                            <td>{note.CreatedOn}</td>
                        </tr>`
                });
                noteTable.html(result);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert("failed to load data.");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

When I click on dropdown list items, The table is rendered as I expected. However, the data in each column returned as `undefined`. I've tried debugging using `console.log(id)` and `console.log(note)` to check `id` and `note` passed in the ajax function was ok or not. But the returned data was ok, there is no problems with that. Hope someone could help me out!

Comment: `GetNoteById` action returns only on single object `noteModel` and not the collection. But you are trying to loop thru it in AJAX success. So either you return a collection from the action method or change the AJAX success to treat response as single object instead of collection.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya No, this returned model contains a collection of another instance. You can see the image I attached on the post.

Comment: The collection is inside the `noteModel` model.. so in AJAX success, `data` will be `nodeModel`. and to access the the collection you need to loop thru `data.notices`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya How can I do that inside the ajax function? Could you provide a code snippet? Thanks in advance!

Comment: try changing `$.each(data, function (id, note) {` to `$.each(data.notices, function (id, note) {`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I've tried but the rendered data still `undefined` man.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya When I tried using `console.log(data.notices)` it displays a collection of data that I need. But when I log `console.log(data.notices.courseName) or courseId` it displayed as `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need change your function to:

```
            $.each(data.notices, function (id, note) {

            result += `
                <tr>
                    <td>${note.id}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="/note/NoteDetail/${note.id}" class="nav-link mt-0">${note.name}</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="/note/DowloadNoteFromDB/${note.id}" class="nav-link mt-0">###</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>{note.fileType}</td>
                    <td>{note.createdOn}</td>
                </tr>`
        });
```

Test result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking time and effort to test the function. Because my model `Course` contains a collection of `notices` and in each `notices` there are `1 or N further notice` so I figure out that I need to loop through `data.notices or note` to be able to access data what I need, and it worked now! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(data, function (item) {
                        /* this is what I tried to debug 
                        there is no problem with the data 
                        but when it is renderd, it returned undefined */

                        

                        result += `
                            <tr>
                                <td>${item.courseId}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="/note/NoteDetail/${item.courseId}" class="nav-link mt-0">${item.courseName}</a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="/note/DowloadNoteFromDB/${item.courseId}" class="nav-link mt-0">###</a>
                                </td>
                                <td>{item.fileType}</td>
                                <td>{item.createdOn}</td>
                            </tr>`
                    });
```

Comment: could you give more description on the snippets? I've your way but it did not worked.